# Pagination of data in Flutter with Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm writing an app with a database of users. I want to show these to people on the app, and as such, in order to limit the download of data, I'm using the standard Firebase pagination concept:

`.startAtDocument(lastDocumentSeen)`

The problem is, I have no idea what actually happens when the 'read head' gets to the end of the database? Does Firebase/Flutter loop back and start to look at the top of the database again? If not, how does it signal to me that I've reached the end?

I've done quite extensive googling about this, and searched StackOverflow too, but can't seem to find any clear answers - does anyone know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a query like this:

```
collectionRef.orderBy("something").startAfter(cursor).limit(10)
```

If there are not enough documents to return 10 results, Firestore will simply return however many documents are left. It does not perform any tricks beyond that.

Comment: Hey @Frank Yes, exactly that. So if I get fewer than my requested results, that essentially means I'm at the end of the database?

Comment: Yup. If you want to only show a "show more" link if you *know* there are more items, you'll want to always load an extra item that you don't show. So you `limit(11)`, show at most 10, and then you know that if you got 11 items, there's a next page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use fetch_more package for pagination, it’s easy to use. You can see an example in the Example tab.

https://pub.dev/packages/fetch_more